# How do you know the correct name to use for X11 fonts for XTerm*faceName or xterm -fa <NAME>?

Tags: fonts, xterm

I am using Mac OS X 10.8 and XQuartz 2.7.2.  I have downloaded and placed several TrueType fonts named `*.ttf` in my `/Users/<name>/.fonts` directory.  Upon running XQuartz several files including `fonts.dir` are created.  This file has X11 font names of various encodings, etc. for each font I've installed.

My trouble is that I can't always "figure out" the correct name to use in `xterm -fa <NAME>` or in my `.Xresources XTerm*faceName` entry.  For some fonts the core font name as listed in the detailed X11 font name in the `fonts.dir` file works whereas for others it doesn't.

Comment: If it helps: the [FreeBSD 10.2 manual page for xterm(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xterm&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) includes information on `-fa` and the _faceName_ resource.

Comment: And what about 2024? Without `xterm` and no `/etc/share` ?

Answer (score 27):

The following one-liner has often helped me a lot to find the correct font name:

```
$ fc-list | cut -f2 -d: | sort -u
```

Especially with Japanese fonts like 'IPAX0208Mincho', I would never have been able to guess the correct name.
If you don't mind a little more typing effort, you might even prefer

```
$ fc-list | cut -f2 -d: | sort -u | less -r
```

to get a paged output.

Answer (score 7):

You can use xfontsel to get the right name:

```
$ xfontsel
```

[image]

Chose the font you are interested in and then click on the "Select" button. That will copy the font name to the clipboard. Use that name to run xterm. E.g.:

```
$ xterm -font -adobe-helvetica-*-r-normal-*-12-120-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

Can't get it to work on my system (linux) using "-fa" but "-font" works.

Comment: Yes, I knew to use xfontsel to get the X11 font name and use xterm -font to select it.  What's strange is that for some fonts I can use xterm -fa <simple font name> and it works fine on other fonts it doesn't.  I think you must have to have a very specific spelling of the <simple font name> because if I take a font where it works and change one letter it doesn't work anymore.  So, my basic question is how do you systematically determine the "correct" <simple font name> such that xterm -fa works.

Comment: @JasonWaldrop Ah. In that case, I'm stumped.

Comment: If it helps (from the man page): "… though xfd accepts a "-fa"  option  to denote FreeType fonts), xfontsel has not been similarly extended …"

Comment: @JasonWaldrop you might be interested in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FontBook to load the font, it will display the correct name to use with `xterm -fa`.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing are entries in the `fonts.alias` file:

```
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi/fonts.alias
```

What this file does is provide short names ("aliases") for X Window fonts that are installed. When you try to use a short name that isn't in the file, you get behavior like this when starting xterm:

```
lansdale:~> xterm -xrm \*font:courr12
xterm: cannot load font "courr12"
```

(The xterm does come up and runs with a default, different font)

The `fonts.alias` file exists because of the long length of X11 font names. For example, courr12 is the short name for:

```
-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso10646-1
```

[The long names are actually 14 different editable fields stitched together with dashes/hyphens. Run program xfontsel to see them; it will start with all fields showing with an asterisk, meaning not set to something specific.]

Each line in the file begins with a short name (an alias), a blank, then the long name it points/refers to. This way, you don't have to use the long name all the time, just set up an alias and use that. When putting a new line in the file, you decide what the short name will be, only the full X11 name has to have a font file installed on the system.

When I first cut my teeth on Unix systems in the 1990s, I ran across courr12 and later came to desire font it (Courier 'Roman' size 12) for my xterms. On HP/UX and Solaris, the `fonts.alias` file already had `courr12`, so I could just put `"XTerm*font: courr12"` in my `.Xdefaults` file and everything would work fine.

Comment: I found that file here: `/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/fonts.alias`